# How to add dsupport for jsonv2 in snowflake rest api

Tags: rest, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Doing a snowflake rest API call to get the status of the submitted job, but getting below error.

Request curl is

```
curl --location 'https://org-account.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements/<id>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'User-Agent: service-client'
```

```
{
    "code": "391917",
    "message": "Invalid parameter. Only the jsonv2 format is allowed through this endpoint. Please check sql api query result format-related settings."
}
```

How do I add support for jsonv2 in snowflake rest api?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - the error message says that only jsonv2 format is allowed so I'm not sure why you think you need to add support for this format? The error message indicates that it doesn't think that what you are submitting is in this format. According to the documentation (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/handling-responses#checking-the-status-of-the-statement-execution-and-retrieving-the-data), the format of the command should be "curl -i -X GET..." but in your question you seem to be missing the GET

Comment: @NickW By default curl uses GET unless -X is specified for a different method. I believe this might be related to the change introduced [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2021-11-bcr#snowflake-sql-api-changes-to-the-process-of-submitting-sql-statements)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute this without problems:

```bash
curl -i -X GET \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "User-Agent: myApplicationName/1.0" \
    -H "X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT" \
    "https://myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements/01ac3f08-0402-f66c-001e-248300fad446"
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/sql-api/submitting-requests#example-of-a-request

I don't see any significant difference between your code or mine though.

The response was, as expected:

```json
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 12 May 2023 23:08:43 GMT
Expect-CT: enforce, max-age=3600
Link: </api/v2/statements/id1?requestId=id2&partition=0>; rel="first",</api/v2/statements/id3?requestId=id4&partition=0>; rel="last"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Country: United States
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: : 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 839
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "resultSetMetaData" : {
    "numRows" : 1,
    "format" : "jsonv2",
    "partitionInfo" : [ {
      "rowCount" : 1,
      "uncompressedSize" : 5
    } ],
    "rowType" : [ {
      "name" : "1",
      "database" : "",
      "schema" : "",
      "table" : "",
      "precision" : 1,
      "collation" : null,
      "type" : "fixed",
      "byteLength" : null,
      "scale" : 0,
      "length" : null,
      "nullable" : false
    } ]
  },
  "data" : [ ["1"] ],
  "code" : "090001",
  "statementStatusUrl" : "/api/v2/statements/id5?requestId=id6",
  "requestId" : "id7",
  "sqlState" : "00000",
  "statementHandle" : "id8",
  "message" : "Statement executed successfully.",
  "createdOn" : 1683932687219
}
```

I then tried an exact copy paste of your statement - which was successful too:

```
curl --location 'https://myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com/api/v2/statements/my_long_id' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'X-Snowflake-Authorization-Token-Type: KEYPAIR_JWT' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer my_long_token' \
--header 'User-Agent: service-client'
```